# Understanding the http request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have written a sample code for sending a POST request using jQuery AJAX. Whenever a request is made I'm getting the error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load. Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 403

I'm not sure whether the mistake is from my side or at the back-end. So I want to know what `error code 403` means and also what cause this. Also I'm posting my sample code, note that the URL is a dummy one, so there's any mistakes please let me know.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  "use strict";
  $('form.form-email').submit(function(event) {
    if (event.preventDefault) 
      event.preventDefault();
    else 
      event.returnValue = false;

    var validateForm = $(this).closest('form-form-email');
    //var sample = validateForm.serialize();
    var name = $('#name').val();
    var dd = $('#dd').val();
    var contactNum = $('#contactNum').val();
    var email = $('#email').val();
    var time = $('#time').val();
    var sendData = {
      sendname: name,
      sendDD: dd,
      sendcontact: contactNum,
      sendemail: email,
      sendtime: time
    };
    console.log(sendData);

    debugger;
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      contentType: "application/json",
      url: 'dummyurl',
      data: sendData,
      dataType: "json",
      // data:$(this).serialize(),
      success: function(result) {
        console.log(data);
      },
      error: function(error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    });
  });
  // });
});
```

```html
<form id="contactPage" class="form-email">
  <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg input-sm validate-required" id="name" placeholder="Contact Person" />
  <div class="form-group">
    <select class="form-control input-lg bfh-countries wrapper-dropdown-2 validate-required" id="dd" data-country="US"></select>
  </div>
  <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg validate-required" id="contactNum" placeholder="Contact Number" />
  <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg validate-required validate-email" id="email" placeholder="Email Address" />
  <input type="time" class="form-group form-control input-lg validate-required" id="time" placeholder="Time" />
  <input type="submit" class="form-group form-control" value="Contact" />
</form>
```

Comment: The fact that you're getting a pre-flight response would indicate that this is a cross-domain request. If so, it sounds like the receiving domain does not accept them. Your next steps depend on whether you have access to that domain or not.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=http+status+codes https://www.google.com/search?q=xmlhttprequest+preflight

Answer (score 0):

This is clearly a backend issue, you should probably allow CORS in backend and then from frontend when POST request is made, first it sends a preflight call as OPTIONS, if it is a success then actual POST request which you made will be sent

Comment: I think this has something to do with X-frame options of the website which he is trying to access via Ajax call